# Scala pattern matching on generic Map

Tags: scala, generics

Whats the best way to handle generics and erasure when doing pattern matching in Scala (a Map in my case). I am looking for a proper implementation without compiler warnings. I have a function that I want to return Map[Int, Seq[String]] from. Currently the code looks like:

```
def teams: Map[Int, Seq[String]] = {
    val dateam = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, Seq[String]]

    // data.attributes is Map[String, Object] returned from JSON parsing (jackson-module-scala)
    val teamz = data.attributes.get("team_players")
    if (teamz.isDefined) {
      val x = teamz.get
      try {
        x match {
          case m: mutable.Map[_, _] => {
            m.foreach( kv => {
              kv._1 match {
                case teamId: String => {
                  kv._2 match {
                    case team: Seq[_] => {
                      val tid: Int = teamId.toInt
                      dateam.put(tid, team.map(s => s.toString))
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            })
          }
        }
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          logger.error("Unable to convert the team_players (%s) attribute.".format(x), e)
        }
      }

      dateam
    } else {
      logger.warn("Missing team_players attribute in: %s".format(data.attributes))
    }
    dateam.toMap
}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler warnings that this code generates.

Comment: [Same code after a little refactoring](http://pastebin.com/1mhbj9WE).

Comment: A lot of context is necessary here -- first off, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? You're only "pattern matching" with one case, so the intent isn't clear. What errors are you getting and for what inputs?

Comment: I have some JSON data that I know is Map[Int, Seq[String]]. Unfortunately from the Jackson library I get Map[String, Object], so I was looking for some sort of casting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be reasonable to use `for` comprehension (with some built in pattern matching). Also we could take into account that `Map` is a list of tuples, in our case of `(String, Object)` type. As well we will ignore for this example probable exceptions, so:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

def convert(json: Map[String, Object]): HashMap[Int, Seq[String]] = {

  val converted = for {
    (id: String, description: Seq[Any]) <- json
  } yield (id.toInt, description.map(_.toString))

  HashMap[Int, Seq[String]](converted.toSeq: _*)
}
```

So, our `for` comprehension taking into account only tuples with `(String, Seq[Any])` type, then combines converted `String` to `Int` and `Seq[Any]` to `Seq[String]`. And makes `Map` to be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Scala library to handle it. There are some based on Jackson (Play's [ScalaJson](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaJson), for instance -- see [this article](http://mandubian.com/2013/02/21/play-json-stand-alone/) on using it stand-alone), as well as libraries not based on Jackson (of which my preferred is [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/), though you could also go with [Spray-Json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json)).

These libraries, and others, *solve this problem*. Doing it by hand is awkward and prone to errors, so don't do it.